# Machine Learning udacity

Tags: python, machine-learning

What does these codes mean?

can you explain to me :

```
features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test = makeTerrainData() 
def submitAccuracy():
    return acc
```

Answer (score 1):

In machine learning development you want to split your available data into train/test sets and if possible an additional validation set. You do this to test for overfitting and ensure your model is generalizable to unseen observations. The final validation set is often useful because without knowing it, often users will try to optimize their parameters on the test partition accuracy, and in doing so are basically giving hints to the model of what that data is. The validation set is useful to test that this hasn't occurred and your model isn't overfit.

With only seeing the code provided, train_features  likely corresponds to the actual data being used to develop the model, in the train partition. The labels are the categories you are trying to predict.

The test partition is simply a random sample of your available data. Features/labels are the same as above.

You want to build the model off of the training data, and assess accuracy on the test partition.

Sebastian Rascka provides a marvelous overview of machine learning in python. The code samples and some explanations can be found at https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/tree/master/code